# a href onClick is called on page start up (before clicking on the link)

Tags: ajax, primefaces, ftp, href

I have a primefaces datatable with a column containing links to ftp files:

```
<p:column sortBy="emplacementlivrable" filterBy="emplacementlivrable">
<a href="ftp://#{spec.emplacementlivrable}" onclick="#{respSpecController.connectToFtpServer()}" target="_blank">#{spec.emplacementlivrable}
</a>
</p:column>
```

I need the method to connect to the ftp server to be executed only if the user clicks on the link. But when I debug, I can see that it calls that method on page start up and not only when clicking the link.

Is there a why to prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange, I don't know why. But this should work:

```
<p:commandLink value="#{spec.emplacementlivrable}" 
               actionListener="#{respSpecController.connectToFtpServer()}" 
               oncomplete="window.open('ftp://#{spec.emplacementlivrable}'); return false;" 
               />
```